# Phonegap Android App Not scrolling pages

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a phonegap based android app by using jquery mobile,  but pages in my application are not scrolling and on touch events, I am getting these messages in android logcat -

12-26 11:37:50.023: WARN/webview(11326): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
12-26 11:37:50.429: INFO/InputReader(1489): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0 
12-26 11:37:50.429: INFO/InputDispatcher(1489): Delivering touch to current input target 
12-26 11:37:50.554: INFO/InputReader(1489): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1 
12-26 11:37:50.554: INFO/InputDispatcher(1489): Delivering touch to current input target 
12-26 11:37:50.554: VERBOSE/webview(11326): singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent  getEditableSupport  FASLE

also,(it might be helpful) I am using photoswipe.js for touch based image gallery. Can somebody tell what might be the reason for pages not scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it might be helpful for other people. the issue was that one of my html pages had one iframe showing youtube video content,apparently android(particularly versions before android 3 dont like iframes). Fixed it by removing the iframe.